# I get an error once placed a plugin inside a function only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having trouble with this error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null`.

So if you visit this page here: http://loai.directory/reiss/profile and view the console errors, you will find Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null

Well, I am using a grid system, the plugin can be found here: http://loai.directory/reiss/assets/js/grid-system.js

I have the grid inside a tab plugin that I have created, the code for the tab function can be found here: http://loai.directory/reiss/assets/js/main.js it's called Tabs and it is placed around line 58...

So that error above is showing for the Grid System, however after a long day of debugging I found that when I removed the tabs function, the error has gone and the grid system worked perfectly! So the problem occurring because of the tabs function.

**Update:** in my tabs function here:

```
//Tabs ///
    $('.tabs').each(function() {
        var $tabs = $(this);
        $tabs.find('.section-body > div:not(:first-child)').hide().end().find('.section-head a:eq(0)').addClass('active').end().find('.section-head a').on('click', function() {
            $tabs.find('.section-head a').removeClass('active').end().find('.section-body > div:eq(' + $(this).index() + ')').show().siblings().hide();
            $(this).addClass('active');
        });
    });
```

Do you see the bit that says `$(this).index()` when I removed that bit, the Grid System worked! I believe now that the Grid system is somehow clashing with the Tabs section from `$(this).index()` is there any other way to achieve the same rusalts without using $(this).index()? or ID's

Comment: In the JSFiddle, lines 84 - 87, you're getting a bunch of CSS and looking for the property "content". It's not there. Looks like the rest of that code segment depends on finding "content" and getting some sort of numeric value. Console "a", no "content" in the list. Console "o", coming up blank. The return statement on line 87 depends on "o" not being blank.

Comment: Is that line 84 87 in the CSS file mate?

Comment: No, in the Javascript window.